# Planning to upgrade VS 2005 to VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005

I have installed VS 2010 and want to migrate all code written in VS 2005 to VS 2010.

Please note that we do not have VS 2008, all code are in C# 2.0 and Asp.net 2.0 only.

Can anyone please tell me now what all points need to be considered while migrating.

#### Update:

I have set target framework to 2.0 for all of my Libraries and web projects. It complies without any error!

However, when site opens in IE (Set to  default.aspx), it gives me error as below:

> InternalXmlHelper.vb(9) : error BC30560: 'ExtensionAttribute' is
>   ambiguous in the namespace 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices'.
>
> ```
> <Global.System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute()> _
> ```

Comment: You do not need to keep much points while migrating. VS2010 Migration agent keeps all the track. Since you have used 2005. So I can say , your project will be converted with 0 or few errors that will be recovered easily. You just need to open the solution in VS2010.

Comment: What do you mean by "code upgrade"? Do you want to migrate to .NET 4?

Answer (score 4):

1. Keep all the target framework settings to .NET 2.0. This way, there should be no compilation problem at all.
2. The changes that you *should* see are the solution and project files only.

Answer (score 1):

1. Start with known good solutions in source control (and label—you shouldn't need to go back, but easy to add an extra safety net).
2. Open each solution in VS2010, allow the conversion wizard to do the conversion.
3. Resolve any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, if you're just upgrading VS 2010 you don't really need to consider much.  Just keep backups (any real SCM product will do) and you're good.  You don't have to upgrade your applications' runtime targets at all if you don't want to.

If you're building with CAS policy, you might run into issues with using MSBuild 4.0 to build you 2.0 applications.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, never mind.

My advice is to make sure everyone's "checked in" to your source code provider, and run the conversion wizard and see how it goes.